# ColdFusion : How to link each part of a pie chart to a specific URL?

Tags: coldfusion, pie-chart, cfchart

I've got a basic pie chart with values like this

```
    <cfchartdata item="January" value="503100">
    <cfchartdata item="February" value="720310">
    <cfchartdata item="March" value="688700">
```

I'd like to link each piece of the pie to a specific URL - I don't need to post any variables to the URL.

I tried something like this;

```
<cfchartdata item="January" value="503100" url="januarydata.cfm">
```

but URL is not a valid attribute for 'cfchartdata'

Comment: It doesn't make sense from my standpoint to have JanuaryData.cfm FeburaryData.cfm etc... just monthlyData.cfm?month=January that looks at form or url variables (url in this case).  that's 1 page to maintain, not 12.  but I did give you a way to work this out in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `url` attribute belongs to the [CFChart](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_05.html) tag, not the [CFChartData](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_06.html) tag

URL:

> URL to open if the user clicks item in a data series; the onClick
>   destination page.
>
> You can specify variables within the URL string; ColdFusion passes
>   current values of the variables.
>
> - $VALUE$: the value of the selected row. If none, the value is an empty
>     string.
> - $ITEMLABEL$: the label of the selected item. If none, the
>     value is an empty string.
> - $SERIESLABEL$: the label of the selected
>     series.
> - If none, the value is an empty string, for example: 
>     "somepage.cfm?item=$ITEMLABEL$&series=$SERIESLABEL$&value=$VALUE$
> - "javascript:...": executes a client-side script.

if you want to do a dynamic search you can use the dynamic values above mixed in with static and other CF values.  for example:

```
<cfchart url="someSearchPage.cfm?param1=Static Text&param2=#form.ColdFusionFormVariable#&param3=$ITEMLABEL$" ...>
```

In this example the $ITEMLABEL$ is converted to the label automatically.

**Disclaimer**

---

Before answering your actual question, I should point out that this isn't a good practice and defeats the entire purpose of a dynamic website.  You should consider a single page that accepts a parameter and pulls the data from a database depending on that parameter.  For example `monthlyData.cfm?month=january`

---

The simplest way would be to put the item label in the file name as you confirmed worked in the comments.

```
<cfchart url = "$itemLabel$data.cfm" ...>
```

If you needed to do a little more testing before sending the user along, you could send them to a single ColdFusion page and use `CFSWITCH` / `CFCASE` or good old `CFIF` / `CFELSE` if there aren't that many combinations.

**-or-**

you could use the javaScript: option and run a function that uses window.location depending on the series clicked.

```
javaScript:goto($itemSeries$,$seriesLabel$)
```

The js function may look like:

```
function goto(item,label){
  if(item == "..." && label== "..."){
   document.location = "..."; 
  }else{
   etc...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so how can I request a specific URL from different parts of the piechart without having to post variables?

Comment: Darn. Took too long typing and Travis updated his response again and beat me to it ;-)

Comment: I haven't tried this but another thing you might be able to do is url = "$itemLabel$data.cfm"

Comment: While I agree a single page (with parameters) is better, that is a slick idea :)

Comment: I went with url = "$itemLabel$data.cfm" it suits my purpose better.

Comment: @JackDamery I updated the answer since you confirmed the suggestion in the comments but PLEASE read the disclaimer.

Comment: @JackDamery - Is there a specific reason you *must* use a different script for each month?